# Laplace Transform of $\frac{\sin\alpha t\cos\beta t}t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have problem solving Laplace transform of

$$\frac{\sin\alpha t\cos\beta t}t$$

I have no idea on how it arrived at this answer:

$$\frac{1}{2} \arctan{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{s}}+\frac {1}{2}\arctan{\frac{\alpha-\beta}{s}}$$

Please I want the proof using the definition of Laplace Transform.

Sorry for the format, just a new account here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math stack exchange. Please use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference in writing equations so it becomes understandable and attractive

Answer (score 3):

Let $$F(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\alpha t \cos \beta t}{t} e^{-st}dt$$
$t$ that appears in the denominator suggest to differentiate $F$. Indeed, differentiating we get
$$F'(s) = \int_0^\infty \sin\alpha t\cos\beta t~e^{-st} dt$$
This integral is easier to compute, we have $$F'(s) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha + \beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2 + s^2} - \frac{\alpha - \beta}{(\alpha - \beta)^2 + s^2}\right)$$

Now integrate this function to arrive at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way for me is to start with
$$f(t)=\frac{\sin t}t$$
Then
$$F(s)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}te^{-st}dt$$
$$F^{\prime}(s)=-\int_0^{\infty}\sin te^{-st}dt=\left.\frac{s\sin te^{-st}+\cos te^{-st}}{1+s^2}\right|_0^{\infty}=-\frac1{1+s^2}$$
Then
$$F(s)=-\int\frac{ds}{1+s^2}=-\tan^{-1}s+C$$
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}F(s)=-\frac{\pi}2+C=0$$
So
$$F(s)=\frac{\pi}2-\tan^{-1}s$$
Then
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin\gamma t}te^{-st}dt=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}ue^{-\frac s{\gamma}u}du=F\left(\frac s{\gamma}\right)=\frac{\pi}2-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac s{\gamma}\right)$$
So
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin\alpha t\cos\beta t}te^{-st}dt&=\frac12\left[\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)t}te^{-st}dt+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha-\beta)t}te^{-st}dt\right]\\
&=\frac12\left[\frac{\pi}2-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac s{\alpha+\beta}\right)+\frac{\pi}2-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac s{\alpha-\beta}\right)\right]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The result follows from the fact that
$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ \sin(\alpha t) \cos(\beta t) \right\}(s)=\frac{\alpha  \left(\alpha ^2-\beta ^2+s^2\right)}{\left((\alpha -\beta )^2+s^2\right) \left((\alpha +\beta )^2+s^2\right)}, $$
and [frequency-domain integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) using partial fractions.